# Can someone please explain why this code wont work?

Tags: java

I have been given a program in my class about taking an integer user input from the user between 2 to 10 (n) and print all 'n' digited palindrome numbers.I have come up with a code,but it seems it is not working properly.Myself,I cannot find a logical error,so can someone please help with this code and suggest any changes?

A palindrome number is one which is the same when read from either side of the number.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class npalindrome
    {
    public static void main()
    {
    int i,j,k,l=0,n,r=1,p;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your number between 2 to 10");
    n=sc.nextInt();
    for(i=(int)Math.pow(10,n-1);i<=((int)Math.pow(10,n)-1);i++)
    {
        k=i;
        r=0;

        l=0;

        while(k>=0)
        {
            r=k%10;

            l=(l*10)+r;

            k=k/10;
        }
        if(l==i)
        {
            System.out.println(i+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

There is no output so to speak of, the program runs in an endless loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your k is always greater or equal to 0. So you are stuck in your while:

```
while(k>=0)
```

Maybe you want to change that to just `while(k>0)` ?

Comment: My pleasure, don't forget to check my answer as a solution ;)